# Tally Table - Every Employee's Business Plan on 1st of Month (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

we have a table of employees and their associated Business Plans and start date of each plan. We'd like to create a query to get the 1st of month, the employee, and the business plan that they are on. **If someone changes their plan in the month, go with the last plan in that month**. Thank you. If possible please, show how you would solve this with every date and then show how you would do it if you just want the 1st of the month. [StartDate] <= GETDATE()

```
CREATE TABLE [BusinessPlan] (
[StartDate] date,
[USERNAME] nvarchar(255),
[BasePlan] int,
[PlanId] int)

INSERT INTO [BusinessPlan] VALUES ('12/16/2019', 'LUIS', 300, 5)
INSERT INTO [BusinessPlan] VALUES ('2/19/2020',  'LUIS', 250, 6)
INSERT INTO [BusinessPlan] VALUES ('10/26/2019', 'LUIS', 400, 30)
INSERT INTO [BusinessPlan] VALUES ('3/12/2020',  'WES',  200, 20)
INSERT INTO [BusinessPlan] VALUES ('1/14/2020',  'WES',  350, 21)
INSERT INTO [BusinessPlan] VALUES ('1/26/2020',  'WES',  300, 1)
INSERT INTO [BusinessPlan] VALUES ('9/26/2019',  'WES',  100, 2)
```

```
StartDate   | USERNAME | BasePlan  | PlanId |
----------------------------------------------
12/16/2019  | LUIS     | 300       | 5      |
2/19/2020   | LUIS     | 250       | 6      | 
10/26/2019  | LUIS     | 400       | 30     |
3/12/2020   | WES      | 200       | 20     |
1/14/2020   | WES      | 350       | 21     |
1/26/2020   | WES      | 300       | 1      |
9/26/2019   | WES      | 100       | 2      |
```

Desired Output:

```
FirstOfMon | USERNAME | BasePlan  | PlanId |
----------------------------------------------
10/1/2019  | LUIS     | 400       | 30     |
11/1/2019  | LUIS     | 400       | 30     |
12/1/2019  | LUIS     | 300       | 5      |
1/1/2020   | LUIS     | 300       | 5      |
2/1/2020   | LUIS     | 250       | 6      |
3/1/2020   | LUIS     | 250       | 6      | 
4/1/2020   | LUIS     | 250       | 6      | 
9/1/2019   | WES      | 100       | 2      |
10/1/2019  | WES      | 100       | 2      |
11/1/2019  | WES      | 100       | 2      |
12/1/2019  | WES      | 100       | 2      |
1/1/2020   | WES      | 300       | 1      |
2/1/2020   | WES      | 200       | 20     |
3/1/2020   | WES      | 200       | 20     |
4/1/2020   | WES      | 200       | 20     |
```

Attempted Code:

```
WITH TALLY AS (
)

SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR([StartDate]), MONTH([StartDate]), 1) AS [Date], [USERNAME], [BasePlan], [PlanId]
FROM [BusinessPlan]
WHERE [StartDate] <= GETDATE()
ORDER BY [USERNAME], [StartDate]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this..

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=467667c0899b373b52ab18106c38295d

```
with data
  as (select distinct 
             dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,max(startdate) over()),0) as max_end_date_month
            ,dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,min(startdate) over(partition by username)),0) as min_start_date_month
            ,username                
        from businessplan
     )
    ,businessplan_data
     as(
        select *,row_number() over(partition by username
                                               ,dateadd(m,datediff(m,0,startdate),0) 
                                       order by startdate desc) as rnk
          from businessplan
       ) 
    ,generate_data
     as(
 select row_number() over(order by (select null)) as rnk
   from master..spt_values
       )
    ,user_dates
    as(
select username
       ,dateadd(m,rnk-1,min_start_date_month) as start_dt
       ,dateadd(m,rnk,min_start_date_month) as end_dt
  from data d
  join generate_data gd
    on gd.rnk<=datediff(m,min_start_date_month,max_end_date_month)+1
      )
   ,user_dates_data
   as(
   select ud.start_dt
         ,ud.end_dt
         ,ud.username
         ,max(case when startdate is not null then start_dt end)
           over(partition by ud.username order by start_dt) as grp
         ,bp.baseplan
         ,bp.planid
     from user_dates ud
left join businessplan_data bp
      on ud.username=bp.username
     and bp.startdate>=ud.start_dt
     and bp.startdate<ud.end_dt
     and bp.rnk=1 
     )
  select start_dt as first_of_month
         ,end_dt as end_of_month
         ,username
         ,max(baseplan) over(partition by username,grp) as baseplan
         ,max(planid) over(partition by username,grp) as planid
    from user_dates_data
```